# Screen Capture Need currently use'r started application

Tags: c#, screen-capture, windows

Need to know what applications are currently open: All the Application's in the Task Manager.

This is for screen capture, so I need some access to location of those application on the screen if possible.

Using .net c# Expression encoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969325.aspx) of which windows appear in the taskbar.

Anyway, something like this should get across the general idea. You can sort the details out yourself now that you know where to look.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public delegate bool CallBack(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

public class EnumTopLevelWindows {

    [DllImport("user32", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(CallBack x, IntPtr y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    public static string GetText(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        // Allocate correct string length first
        int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
        GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000;

    public static void Main() 
    {
        CallBack myCallBack = new CallBack(EnumTopLevelWindows.Report);
        EnumWindows(myCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public static bool Report(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (GetParent(hWnd) == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //window is a non-owned top level window
            if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                //window is visible
                int style = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE).ToInt32();
                if ((style & WS_EX_APPWINDOW) == WS_EX_APPWINDOW)
                {
                    //window has WS_EX_APPWINDOW style
                    Console.WriteLine(GetText(hWnd));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'll have to look into your code for a bit... was working on the enumtoplevelwindows .... Well today hopefully I'll get everything going and ill post an update later..
I was actually working on making a class to work with all the messy WMI.
It just has no beauty in my eyes. :D well thanks I'll give you a heads up when i looked through this.

Comment: Thanks, your code made me advance and understand this more a lot but one question. What does if (GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER) == IntPtr.Zero) do ? Was kinda hard understanding it

Comment: Hmm, is it that the IntPtr.Zero represents the desktop/owner and that statement means if the current application owner is the desktop then proceed?

Comment: The comment explains it. It tests that the window is not owned.

Comment: @Reza If this code is helpful to you you should up-vote it and accept it as an answer.

Comment: @David Heffernan, was gonna up vote and pick you but wanted to be sure I get this done before. Thanks, I think I figured out most of the things I need to understand... and the comment did not explain the functionality but thats alright I figured it out thanks.

Comment: @Reza Thanks. The comments are terse, but they are meant to be read alongside the MSDN article I linked to. Then they should make sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use managed System.Diagnostic.Processes class:

```
Process[] running = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process p in running)
  Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, the problem with that it's the processes running and not the application. Best example would be to open the task manager and see the difference in the tabs of application and process. I need only the application ones.

Comment: Then you could use EnumWindows API